# Can solr point into a certain point in a document?

Tags: 7, search

I have very long documents (around 100 pages when printed) that I need to index with Apache Solr Search. Is it possible to index the pages with solr in such a way that clicking the result from the result page takes the user into the right document and **into the right place** in the document?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily (unless there is a module I don't know of which does it).

Solr can return highlighted terms, you can use this highlighting, to preprocess the node when being displayed to insert an anchor tag (after removing the ems), you cold append this tag to the search results page.

Another way would be to index the pages separately. So you could at least link to the correct page (even if is a fragment id) when showing the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to this would be to either create book pages for the docs, or have some sort of parent/child relationships, so they all get index separately, and will return the correct pages and spots, but they will all be organized. That is the way I would do it hands-down.

Instead of finding a solution to link to a certain point in the docs, I would be more focused on how I could organize the actual documents in a better fashion.